# Grouping cells falling within an hour - Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following DataFrame:

```py
Blast_hole  Tag detector ID Detection_location       Detection Time
190          385189144               CV23           24/02/2019 2:15:09 PM
148          385522358               CV23           24/02/2019 2:23:58 PM
136          385321882               CV23           24/02/2019 2:25:07 PM
238          385433175               CV23           25/02/2019 5:44:37 PM
89           385381344               CV23           25/02/2019 6:19:32 PM
177          385391526               CV23           25/02/2019 6:42:49 PM
138          385732572               CV23           3/03/2019 8:52:38 PM
145          385861350               CV23           3/03/2019 9:02:50 PM
196          385599574               CV23           3/03/2019 9:31:24 PM
```

I want to group rows, by `Detection Time`, where three detections occur within one hour.

#### Code:

```py
df1['Detection Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Detection Date & Time'], errors = 'coerce')

s = df1.resample('H',on='Detection Date & Time')['Detection_Location'].transform('size')

df1 = df1[s.sort_index() >= 3]


df1 = df1.sort_values(by =['Detection Date & Time'])

df1['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date and Time'])
df1['Detection Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Detection Date & Time'])


f = lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))
df2=(df1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Detection Date & Time',freq='H'),
                 df1.Detection_Location]).agg({
        'Blast Hole': f,
        'East Coordinate': f,
        'North Coordinate': f,
        'Tag Detector ID': f,
        'Collar':f,
        'Detection Date & Time' : ['first','last','size']})
               .reset_index()
               .rename(columns = {'Detection Date & Time' : '', '<lambda>':''}))
```

The problem is this code is taking hour by hour and looking are there 3 detection within an hour. Like it would detect that between 2.15 to 2.25 Pm on 24.02.2019 there were 3 detection, but it would not detect detection falling within one hour but outside a single hour like on 25.02.2019 between 5.44 pm to 6.42 pm there are 3 entries but it is beyond 1 single hour like 5 or 6 pm so it will not detect that.

#### Current Result:

```py
Detection_Location   Blast Hole                Tag Detector ID Detection Start Time   Detection end time Tags
              CV23  190,148,136  385189144,385522358,385321882  2019-02-24 14:15:09  2019-02-24 14:25:07    3
```

#### Expected Result:

```
Detection_Location              Blast Hole         Tag Detector ID             Detection Start Time   Detection end time Tags
              CV23             190,148,136    385189144,385522358,385321882     2019-02-24 14:15:09  2019-02-24 14:25:07    3
              CV23             238,89,177     385433175,385381344,385391526     2019-02-25 17:44:09  2019-02-25 18:42:09    3
              CV23             138,145,196    385732572,385861350,385599574     2019-03-03 20:52:09  2019-03-03 21:31:09    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a multi-step processes:

- Create the dataframe
- Clean the dataframe

  - Remove any rows where `Detection Data & Time` is `NaN`

```py
# get the data in
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls')

# rename as needed
df.rename(columns={'Detection_location': 'location',
                   'Detection Time': 'date_time',
                   'Tag detector ID': 'id'}, inplace=True)

df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], errors = 'coerce')

df.dropna(inplace=True)


 Blast_hole         id location           date_time
        190  385189144     CV23 2019-02-24 14:15:09
        148  385522358     CV23 2019-02-24 14:23:58
        136  385321882     CV23 2019-02-24 14:25:07
        238  385433175     CV23 2019-02-25 17:44:37
         89  385381344     CV23 2019-02-25 18:19:32
        177  385391526     CV23 2019-02-25 18:42:49
        138  385732572     CV23 2019-03-03 20:52:38
        145  385861350     CV23 2019-03-03 21:02:50
        196  385599574     CV23 2019-03-03 21:31:24
```

- Organized the dataframe into separate dataframes based on the location

  - assumes there will be multiple locations
  - sort by `date_time`
  - use `diff` to calculate the time delta
  - using `periods=2` will satisfy the condition of finding  3 values within a specific time frame.
- Find the relevant rows of data

  - Find 3 consecutive rows of data that occur within 1 hour
  - Because `periods=2`, grab the rows where `diff <= '1 hours'`
  - For each row matching the condition, grab the previous 2 rows

```py
locs = df.location.unique().tolist()

# create a dict of dataframe based upon location
df_locs = {loc: df[df.location == loc].copy() for loc in locs}

# organize data in the dict, create diff
combined_vals = list()
for loc in df_locs.keys():
    df_locs[loc].sort_values('date_time', inplace=True)
    df_locs[loc]['diff'] = df_locs[loc]['date_time'].diff(periods=2)
    df_locs[loc].reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    relevant_row_indices = df_locs[loc][df_locs[loc]['diff'] <= '1 hours'].index.values

    # create a list of lists containing the the values to combine
    for row in relevant_row_indices:
        x = df_locs[loc].iloc[row-2:row+1, :-1].to_string(header=False,
                                                          index=False,
                                                          index_names=False).split('\n')

        # in order to properly split everything, an extra space is need after the location
        x = [y.replace(loc, f'{loc} ') for y in x]
        vals = [ele.strip().split('  ') for ele in x]
        vals = list(zip(*vals))
        vals = [','.join(x.strip() for x in y) for y in vals]
        combined_vals.append(vals)
```

#### combined_values:

```py
[['190,148,136',
  '385189144,385522358,385321882',
  'CV23,CV23,CV23',
  '2019-02-24 14:15:09,2019-02-24 14:23:58,2019-02-24 14:25:07'],
 ['238,89,177',
  '385433175,385381344,385391526',
  'CV23,CV23,CV23',
  '2019-02-25 17:44:37,2019-02-25 18:19:32,2019-02-25 18:42:49'],
 ['138,145,196',
  '385732572,385861350,385599574',
  'CV23,CV23,CV23',
  '2019-03-03 20:52:38,2019-03-03 21:02:50,2019-03-03 21:31:24']]
```

### Create a new dataframe with combined_values:

```py
df_combined = pd.DataFrame(combined_vals, columns=df.columns)

# Remove repetitious location values
df_combined['location'] = df_combined['location'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x.split(',')))[0])

# Create start time column
df_combined['start'] = df_combined['date_time'].str.split(',', expand=True)[0]

# Create end time column
df_combined['end'] = df_combined['date_time'].str.split(',', expand=True)[2]  
df_combined.drop(columns='date_time', inplace=True)
```

#### Final:

```py
  Blast_hole                             id location                start                  end
 190,148,136  385189144,385522358,385321882     CV23  2019-02-24 14:15:09  2019-02-24 14:25:07
  238,89,177  385433175,385381344,385391526     CV23  2019-02-25 17:44:37  2019-02-25 18:42:49
 138,145,196  385732572,385861350,385599574     CV23  2019-03-03 20:52:38  2019-03-03 21:31:24
```

- `Tags` can easily be added as a column, but I didn't add it here

  - `df_combined['Tags'] = 3`

Comment: Amazing Trenton !! Works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def one_hour(df_in):
  location = df_in.Detection_location.values[0]
  b_hole = ", ".join(str(x) for x in df_in.Blast_hole.values)
  n_tag = ", ".join(str(x) for x in df_in.Tag_detector_ID.values)
  start = df_in.index.values[0]
  end = df_in.index.values[-1]
  c_tag = len(df_in.index.values)

  b = {"Location":location,"Blast_hole":[b_hole],"Tag_detector_ID":[n_tag],"Start":[start],"End":[end],"count_tag":[c_tag]}
  df_new = pd.DataFrame(b)
  return df_new
df2 = df.groupby(lambda x:np.ceil((x+1)/3),axis=0).apply(one_hour).reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

as i understand, it's needed to be grouped by the next 3th detection.

eg. index [0,1,2] is group 1, [3,4,5] is group 2.....

so the code above for your ref. Please advise your thinks on this.

Comment: Hi @Rean, Its not by index but its about the detection falling within a time range of 1 hour from each other so they may be closely lying in the data like 1 2 3, or they may at different locations, but we need to group all detection lying within the 1 hour hour window, which are more than 3 in number. lets say the first one is at 2.53, then 3.16, 3.45, 3.50...all lie in one hour window and are more than 3 so should be counted in as a group. Thats what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

yah let try this one. below function for create group by every 60 mins:

```
gr_list = []
gr = 0
for idx,tim in df.Detection_Time.iteritems():

  if is_end == True or idx == 0:
    first_time = tim
    gr_top = idx
  delta = tim - first_time

  if delta.seconds < 3600:
    gr_it = gr_top
    try:
      delta_next = df.Detection_Time[idx+1] - first_time
      if delta_next.seconds > 3600:
        is_end = True
      else:
        is_end = False
    except:
      pass
  else:
    pass
  gr_list.append(gr_it)

df['gr'] = gr_list
```

then loop through each group and return new dataframe:

```
def one_hour(df_in):
  location = df_in.Detection_location.values[0]
  b_hole = ", ".join(str(x) for x in df_in.Blast_hole.values)
  n_tag = ", ".join(str(x) for x in df_in.Tag_detector_ID.values)
  start = df_in.index.values[0]
  end = df_in.index.values[-1]
  c_tag = len(df_in.index.values)

  b = {"Location":location,"Blast_hole":[b_hole],"Tag_detector_ID":[n_tag],"Start":[start],"End":[end],"count_tag":[c_tag]}
  df_new = pd.DataFrame(b)
  return df_new
df2 = df.groupby('gr').apply(one_hour).reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

Hope this helps!!